# How about each item in the listview to add more data？

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image]

I hope above listview to add more data,Like the above picture.An item can display four data，Where and how much. Balance of time,I just need the local data, do not need to network data.What should I do？hele me.think！
  （My English is not good. Hope you can understand what I mean）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a separate xml file file that provides the row layout to your listview. Try [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on how to use list view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add recycler view dependencies on the app build.gradle file
2. Create an item view, and align views on xml of how a single list item would look.
3. Create recycler view adapter to inflate views and handle clicks
4. Add recycler view on your activity or fragment layout
5. From your activity or fragment, pass in data to your adapter using adapter's constructor.

In general just follow normal implementation of Recycler view. [Click here so see example](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)